# Android : Using horizontal progress bar in android to display downloading process

Tags: java, android, jsoup, android-progressbar

I have a class which create a progress bar in android

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnStartProgress;
    ProgressDialog progressBar;
    private int progressBarStatus = 0;
    private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();

    private long fileSize = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnStartProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartProgress);
        btnStartProgress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
                progressBar.setCancelable(true);
                progressBar.setMessage("File downloading ...");
                progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                progressBar.setProgress(0);
                progressBar.setMax(100);
                progressBar.show();


                progressBarStatus = 0;


                fileSize = 0;

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (progressBarStatus < 100) {


                            progressBarStatus = doSomeTasks();


                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                            progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                                }
                            });
                        }


                        if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {


                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                            progressBar.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

            }

        });

    }


    public int doSomeTasks() {

        while (fileSize <= 1000000) {

            fileSize++;

            if (fileSize == 100000) {
                return 10;
            } else if (fileSize == 200000) {
                return 20;
            } else if (fileSize == 300000) {
                return 30;
            }


        }

        return 100;

    }

}
```

and a code snippet to download a web page

```
Document doc;
        try {
            String url = "http://it.tdt.edu.vn/kind/of/posts/ho%E1%BA%A1t-d%E1%BB%99ng";
            // need http protocol
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://it.tdt.edu.vn/kind/of/posts/tin-tuc-su-kien").get();
//          Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8", url);

            // get page title
            String title = doc.title();
            System.out.println("title : " + title);

            // get all links
            Elements links = doc.select("article section p a[href]");
            for (Element link : links) {

                // get the value from href attribute
                System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------");
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(link.attr("href")).get();

                System.out.println(document.select("section > article section").first());


            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

so, how do I mix this code snippet to to display on the downloading process in progress bar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include a minimal example of your code. For example, imports are not relevant.

Comment: @Lal I have a class which create a progress bar in android which is the first code snippet, so where I gonna place the second code snippet to display on the downloading process in progress bar